# ReactJS Modal component won't close onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I have created a user CRUD api that is linked to a reactJs front end. I have been using the bootstrap components and decied to use the modal component to have edit forms. The only issue is that for some reason when the modal opens, I can not exit it again unless I reload the browser.

The code for the EditUserModal.js is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Modal, Button, Row, Col, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as moment from 'moment';

const BASE_API_URL = `http://localhost:56062/api/users`;

var currentDate = new Date();



export class EditUserModal extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }



    componentDidMount(){
      }

    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(BASE_API_URL,{
            method:'PUT',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({

                Id: event.target.Id.value,
                firstName: event.target.firstName.value,
                lastName: event.target.lastName.value,
                Email: event.target.Email.value,
                mobileNumber: event.target.mobileNumber.value,
                dateOfBirth: event.target.dateOfBirth.value,
                lastModified: currentDate
            })
        })
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then((result) =>
        {
            console.log(result);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log('Failed')
        }
        )
    }

    render(){
        return(

            <Modal
            {...this.props}
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                Edit User
              </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <div className="editFormContainer">
                  <Row>
                      <Col sm={12}>
                          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                          <Form.Group controlId="Id">
                                <Form.Label>User ID</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control name="Id" disabled defaultValue = {this.props.userid} type="text" placeholder="Id" />
                              </Form.Group>
                              <Form.Group controlId="firstName">
                                <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control name="firstName" required  type="text" defaultValue = {this.props.firstname} placeholder="First Name" />
                              </Form.Group>
                              <Form.Group controlId="lastName">
                                <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control name="lastName" required type="text" defaultValue = {this.props.lastname} placeholder="Last Name"  />
                              </Form.Group>
                              <Form.Group controlId="Email">
                                <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control name="Email" required type="email" defaultValue = {this.props.useremail} placeholder="Email e.g. name@example.com" />
                              </Form.Group>
                              <Form.Group controlId="mobileNumber">
                                <Form.Label>Mobile Number</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control name="mobileNumber" required type="text" defaultValue = {this.props.mobilenumber} placeholder="Mobile e.g. 0723218223 or +447236475886" />
                              </Form.Group>
                              <Form.Group controlId="dateOfBirth">
                                <Form.Label>Date of Birth</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control name="dateOfBirth" required type="date" defaultValue = {moment(new Date(this.props.dateofbirth)).format('YYYY-MM-DD')} placeholder="Date of Birth e.g. 05-02-97" />
                              </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Edit User</Button>
                            </Form.Group>

                          </Form>

                      </Col>
                  </Row>
              </div>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

And then for the page the modal is used, the code related is as follows:

```
export class User extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {users:[], addModalShow : false, editModalShow: false}

    }

render(){

    const {users, userid, firstname, lastname, useremail, mobilenumber, dateofbirth, lastmodified} = this.state;
    let addModalClose =() => this.setState({addModalShow:false});
    let editModalClose =() => this.setState({editModalShow:false});

    return(
        <div>
            <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button variant='outline-dark' style={{margin:"auto"}} onClick={()=> this.setState({addModalShow:true})}>
                  Add User
              </Button>
                <AddUserModal show={this.state.addModalShow} onHide={addModalClose} />
              </ButtonToolbar>

        <Table responsive borderless style={{borderRadius:"0.3em"}} striped hover size="sm" variant="dark" className="mt-4">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Id</th>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Mobile Number</th>
       <th>Date of Birth</th>
       <th>Last Modified</th>
       <th>Edit</th>
       <th>Delete</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        {users.map(user=> 


          <tr key = {user.Id}>
            <td>{user.Id}</td>
            <td>{user.firstName}</td>
            <td>{user.lastName}</td>
            <td>{user.Email}</td>
            <td>{user.mobileNumber}</td>
            <td>{moment(new Date(user.dateOfBirth)).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}</td>
            <td>{user.lastModified}</td>
            <td>
              <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button className="mr-2" variant="outline-light" onClick={()=> { ReactDOM.render(<EditUserModal show={true} userid={user.Id} firstname={user.firstName} 
              lastname={user.lastName} useremail={user.Email} mobilenumber={user.mobileNumber} dateofbirth={user.dateOfBirth} onHide = {editModalClose}  /> , document.getElementById('root')) }}>
              Edit User
              </Button>
              </ButtonToolbar>
              </td>
              <td>
              <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={()=> this.deleteUser(user.Id)} >Delete</Button>
              </td>

          </tr>
          )}
   </tbody>
 </Table>

 </div>
    )
}

}
```

Why is the modal not exiting properly? or what way could i make this possible? Clicking off the modal, cancel or the X button don't seem to close the modal.

======================= EDIT =======================================

I realized, when the modal is in that state, and I submit the edit form, the console displays a "Failed" message from thi chunk of code, even though when I refresh the page, it successfully loads the new edited information.

```
handleSubmit(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(BASE_API_URL,{
            method:'PUT',
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({

                Id: event.target.Id.value,
                firstName: event.target.firstName.value,
                lastName: event.target.lastName.value,
                Email: event.target.Email.value,
                mobileNumber: event.target.mobileNumber.value,
                dateOfBirth: event.target.dateOfBirth.value,
                lastModified: currentDate
            })
        })
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then((result) =>
        {
            console.log(result);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log('Failed')
        }
        )
    }
```

Comment: You are passing show={true} always. Shouldn't you pass editModalShow prop instead of {true}?

Comment: When I do that, I just get a white screen after clicking the modal button. @G_S

Comment: Also, the way I have it now basically gives a white screen too but atleast shows the modal form. but i just cant exit it.

Comment: Any error in console when you are getting white screen.?

Comment: @G_S it says:
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Comment: @G_S I also edited the question with a further thing i noticed

Comment: I don't think the piece of code for submit has anything to do with close functionality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206624/discussion-between-zadders-and-g-s).

Comment: @g_s  I wasn't trying to get that submit button to close the modal. I wanted the close button, cancel and when someone clicks off the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sketch... but something like this:

```js
export class User extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {users:[], addModalShow : false, editModalShow: false, currentEdited: null}
    }

     addModalClose =() => this.setState({addModalShow:false});
     editModalClose =() => this.setState({editModalShow:false});


render(){
    const {users, currentEdited} = this.state;
   
    return(
        <div>
            <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button variant='outline-dark' style={{margin:"auto"}} onClick={()=> this.setState({addModalShow:true})}>
                  Add User
              </Button>
                <AddUserModal show={this.state.addModalShow} onHide={this.addModalClose} />
              </ButtonToolbar>

        <Table responsive borderless style={{borderRadius:"0.3em"}} striped hover size="sm" variant="dark" className="mt-4">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Id</th>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Mobile Number</th>
       <th>Date of Birth</th>
       <th>Last Modified</th>
       <th>Edit</th>
       <th>Delete</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        {users.map(user=> 
          <tr key = {user.Id}>
            <td>{user.Id}</td>
            <td>{user.firstName}</td>
            <td>{user.lastName}</td>
            <td>{user.Email}</td>
            <td>{user.mobileNumber}</td>
            <td>{moment(new Date(user.dateOfBirth)).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}</td>
            <td>{user.lastModified}</td>
            <td>
              <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button className="mr-2" variant="outline-light" onClick={()=> { this.setState({ currentEdited: user, editModalShow: true }); }}>
              Edit User
              </Button>
              </ButtonToolbar>
              </td>
              <td>
              <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={()=> this.deleteUser(user.Id)} >Delete</Button>
              </td>

          </tr>
          )}
   </tbody>
 </Table>
    <EditUserModal show={this.state.editModalShow} onHide={this.editModalClose} {...currentEdited}  />
 </div>
    )
}

}
```

Comment: The modal properly closes now, but the button doesn't send the props through to the form thats displayed when the modal opens.

Comment: Can you send a sandbox with your code? e.g https://codesandbox.io

Comment: I actually had to set the props individually while using your technique, but it all works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have hardcoded `show` prop to `true`.

```
<EditUserModal show={this.state.editModalShow} {...otherProps} />
```

```js
export class User extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {users:[], addModalShow : false, editModalShow: false}

    }

render(){

    const {users, userid, firstname, lastname, useremail, mobilenumber, dateofbirth, lastmodified} = this.state;
    let addModalClose =() => this.setState({addModalShow:false});
    let editModalClose =() => this.setState({editModalShow:false});

    return(
        <div>
            <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button variant='outline-dark' style={{margin:"auto"}} onClick={()=> this.setState({addModalShow:true})}>
                  Add User
              </Button>
                <AddUserModal show={this.state.addModalShow} onHide={addModalClose} />
              </ButtonToolbar>

        <Table responsive borderless style={{borderRadius:"0.3em"}} striped hover size="sm" variant="dark" className="mt-4">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Id</th>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Mobile Number</th>
       <th>Date of Birth</th>
       <th>Last Modified</th>
       <th>Edit</th>
       <th>Delete</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        {users.map(user=> 


          <tr key = {user.Id}>
            <td>{user.Id}</td>
            <td>{user.firstName}</td>
            <td>{user.lastName}</td>
            <td>{user.Email}</td>
            <td>{user.mobileNumber}</td>
            <td>{moment(new Date(user.dateOfBirth)).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}</td>
            <td>{user.lastModified}</td>
            <td>
              <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button className="mr-2" variant="outline-light" onClick={()=> { this.setState({ editShowModal: true }); }}>
              Edit User
              </Button>
              <EditUserModal show={this.state.editModalShow} userid={user.Id} firstname={user.firstName} 
                lastname={user.lastName} useremail={user.Email} mobilenumber={user.mobileNumber}
                 dateofbirth={user.dateOfBirth} onHide={editModalClose}  />
              </ButtonToolbar>
              </td>
              <td>
              <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={()=> this.deleteUser(user.Id)} >Delete</Button>
              </td>

          </tr>
          )}
   </tbody>
 </Table>
   

 </div>
    )
}

}
```

Comment: this is invalid, when i had the code like this, it only shows the last entry in the table. i'm unsure why it's not getting the right information.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to include the modal in your mapping.I would rather pull it out as an single component instance that passed currently edited props

Comment: @gaditzkhori How would I go about doing so though?

Comment: Because the way Zohaib @Zohaib exaplined, would basically end up loading all the users and just displaying the last object in the api like so. https://gyazo.com/e061706c30ab5769c66365f39bb511ba